# How do I read this weird server response and get the "success" key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object

I am using this jQuery basic ajax reader:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('data is', data);
    }
});
```

The full server response I get is:

```
jQuery17107194540228229016_1350987657731({"action":"", "type":"", "callerId":""},
 {"errorCode":0,"errorDescription":"OK","success":true,"payload":null});
```

However, when I try to output it with the `console.log('data is,data);` the output I get is:

```
data is  Object {action: "", type: "", callerId: ""}
```

**How do I receive the other part of the server response?**

ie: The part that tells me `success:true`:

```
{"errorCode":0,"errorDescription":"OK","success":true,"payload":null}
```

Comment: show us the line by which u r passing the response from the server

Comment: Why would you _manually_ want to check if the `success` property is true in the _success callback function_?? if the success function is called, success will always be true anyway. Perhaps [the inner workings of jQuery's ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/extending-ajax/) might show you what properties you can try to access, like `jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr`

Comment: I am getting a response from the server. I want to check if the server tells me whether the task was completed successfully or whether there was some kind of error (not server error, but logic error - the string was not valid, the dates are not possible etc.) - this is why I want to check if the request was successful

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid, the line is "console.log('data is',data)" - I can't seem to get the {"errorCode"...null} object - only to the first object.

Comment: @Alon : this is how u r writing to console , i am asking when u send response from server , there in the server u might be using some final line like return or render , tell me that line

Comment: What exactly is this response: `jQuery17107194540228229016_1350987657731({},{});` ? The success function is expecting a single JSON object.

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid, I don't know how the server renders it since I am on the client side and don't have control over it.

Comment: @jfrej - As I argue with the server guy (I asked him to change the format for ({}) and he argues that I need to fit to his format ({},{})) - Can I tell him that the format that he sends is wrong or is there an easy conventional way to read it?

Comment: @Alon : actually i just wanted to make sure whether he has passes correctly as a json response or not , atleast that u can make sure

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid, how do I know that he passes it correctly? the ({},{}) is clearly not a valid json, right? Is there a way I can make sure that I request it properly?

Comment: ur response is coming as json object . first convert it in to json arary , then iterate every element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, I don't know if it will help:

```
success:function(data, second){
                       console.log('data is',data, 'second is ',second);
```

As several people has pointed out, the success function will only return if the request is a success. But if you have some special reason why you want to use those return values, you could add an extra parameter ( I think, still haven't tested it myself ).

Answer (score 1):

success callback from jquery request will always be success even if the response is a 404. As long as the server was reachable, that is always a success. Only when server is not reachable or request got lost in the way the error callback is triggered. From that perspective, you'll always have to analyze the output to see if the result is the desired (that or check the status code of the response. If it's 40x, then it's probably an error from your perspective).

Comment: I just realized, the datatype is "jsonp". shouldn't you be passing the data into a function callback? and where is the contentType?

Comment: As I said - the main issue I had is not with getting the response but it seems the server sends to parameters and I can only manipulate (with the variable "data") the first parameter. My question is how do I reach the second parameter.

Comment: I see... have you influence to the way server responds? I see a response with two hashes, if they would come in one hash, maybe that would validate. either that or your callback has to put those two hashes into one.